PostgreSQL 16.0 permissions check failure
I used postgres to create a schema with tables, and created a readonly group role with one user:
CREATE ROLE data_migration_ro WITH NOLOGIN;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE spp TO data_migration_ro;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA dm_backup TO data_migration_ro;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA dm_backup TO data_migration_ro;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA dm_backup GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO data_migration_ro;

CREATE ROLE dev1 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'pwd';
GRANT data_migration_ro TO dev1;

I use 2 methods to verify the privs-role mapping:
I use postgres admin to run:
SELECT 
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    privilege_type
FROM 
    information_schema.role_table_grants
WHERE 
    grantee = 'data_migration_ro'
ORDER BY 
    table_schema, 
    table_name;

This time, this method works
the my_table was created by another user data_migration, it is created before my GRANT operations
but when I use postgres admin to run \z to check permissions on a table inside the dm_backup
\z my_table;
                            Access privileges
 Schema | Name | Type | Access privileges | Column privileges | Policies
--------+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----------
(0 rows)

It should show the data_migration_ro have r permission at least?
On another cluster,which I didn't create it, just use postgres user to check privileges, but information_schema.role_table_grants does't work.
why could this happen?

To question add: 1) How you created my_table and with what role? 2) When did you create table my_table relative to the GRANT creation you show?  Remember ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES only works on objects created in future. 3) What role are you when you do \z and query the information_schema? 4) Where the grants and the privilege queries done in different concurrent sessions?

1,2)the my_table was created by another user data_migration, it is created before my GRANT operations; 3)I use postgres admin to run \z and query the information_schema 4)this happens in another cluster, which I didn't build it, just use postgres user to check privileges. Thanks for answering

Per previous request add this information to the question text, not as a comment. This ensures that other folks don't have to read  through the comments to get relevant information.

What does this 4)this happens in another cluster, which I didn't build it, just use postgres user to check privileges. mean? Add detailed explanation as update to question text.

You should run \z dm_backup.my_table.

Thanks. Laurenz Albe. You are right I lost the schema name before table name. When added it works. But in a database in another cluster, information_schema.role_table_grants is empty, but I can get privileges  from a spacific table by using \z public.contract; under postgres account
